# Login problem with Rokoko add-on

Tags: add-on, error

[image]

The ROKOKO free plug-in is installed, but there is a problem when logging in to the account and password.

```
Load Handler:
Warning - Text missing for: tips_info
Warning - Text missing for: disable_outline
Warning - Text missing for: set_background
Warning - Text missing for: tips_info
Warning - Text missing for: disable_outline
Warning - Text missing for: set_background

LIB EXISTS? True C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\resources\libs\rokoko-id.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\operators\login.py", line 17, in execute
    if login.login(context.scene.rsl_login_email, password):
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\core\login.py", line 94, in login
    load()
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\core\login.py", line 39, in load
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] 鎵句笉鍒版寚瀹氱殑妯″潡銆

location: <unknown location>:-1



location: <unknown location>:-1
閿欒: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\operators\login.py", line 17, in execute
    if login.login(context.scene.rsl_login_email, password):
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\core\login.py", line 94, in login
    load()
  File "C:\Users\Win10\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.83\scripts\addons\rokoko-studio-live-blender-beta\core\login.py", line 39, in load
    lib = ctypes.CDLL(lib_file)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] 鎵句笉鍒版寚瀹氱殑妯″潡銆?
location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Comment: I also had this problem and found a related github issue: 
https://github.com/Rokoko/rokoko-studio-live-blender/issues/66

Which directed the user to install the "Update for Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable Package" at:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-visual-c-2013-redistributable-package-d8ccd6a5-4e26-c290-517b-8da6cfdf4f10

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Downloading VisualStudioC++ 2013 fixed the problem. Posting this here to help people who may come across the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue I found is that you can not use any CAPS in your email. I generally capitalize my name in my email and it wouldn't take it.

When you use your email as a login, it should have automatically lower cased the email to check it but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and i resolved it by simply uninstalling the Microsoft Store version and installing the MSI from the Blender website.